# Java SQLException ORA-00904

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm having a problem getting a java ResultSet on an Oracle XE 11g release 2 database. I am using the ojdbc6_g.jar driver from Oracle to set up the JDBC connection. I get the following error: ORA-00904: "PARSEBOOL": invalid identifier

This is my Java code:

```
st = s.getConnection().createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT ID, METHODNAME, BEAN, PARSEBOOL, HASHID, ALIAS, WEBTAB FROM METHODS");
```

I am pretty sure this is correct because it all worked while testing on HSQLDB.

The table METHODS is defined as follows in SQLDeveloper:

```
CREATE TABLE "DFOLSTAT"."METHODS"
  (
    "ID"         NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "METHODNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "BEAN"       VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "HASHID"     VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
    "ALIAS"      VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "WEBTAB"     VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "PARSEBOOL"  CHAR(1 BYTE),
    CONSTRAINT "METHODS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "METHODS_HASHID" UNIQUE ("HASHID") USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE         DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE
  )
```

I read about possible errors due to case sensitive column names but when performing a query in SQLDeveloper or the command line, everything works fine. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Siebe

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about this, hence just suggesting you through a comment : I guess it has got something to do with `PARSEBOOL` declared as `CHAR`. Try it with a `VARCHAR2` instead.

Comment: @KazekageGaara using `VARCHAR2` didn't help.

Comment: Can you please try and rename the column "ParseBool" to something different and check? The probable reasons of an `ORA-00904` are either a missing or an invalid identifier for a column. But none seems to be the case here. Simply Baffling. If that doesn't work, try changing your driver as per one of the answers below. Check your trace file or logs which may have more information on this issue.

Comment: If you remove `PARSEBOOL` from the SQL does it work? Or do you get the error for a different column? Also, are you sure there are no other schema/connection that i being used from Java?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a clash with a function name. Try surrounding the column name with double quotes, just as you have in the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Using double quotes also throws the error message. I tried changing the name of the column and no matter what name I give it, it always throws the error message...

Answer (score 0):

the driver you are using seems to be inappropriate...
try with ojdbc14.jar
it is easliy available on oracle's website..
rest code is ok

Comment: I tried the driver you suggested but it didn't work either. I also tried the driver bundled in the SQLDeveloper application but no success either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling your table as follows

```
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT METHODS.ID, METHODS.METHODNAME, 
METHODS.BEAN, METHODS.PARSEBOOL, METHODS.HASHID, METHODS.ALIAS, 
    METHODS.WEBTAB FROM DFOLSTAT.METHODS");
```

or try this

```
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT ID, METHODNAME, BEAN, \"PARSEBOOL\", HASHID, 
ALIAS, WEBTAB FROM METHODS");
```